# How to start the Snort service with logging enabled?

Tags: snort, centos

I setup snort on Centos server and add as a service. When I use `service snortd start` command, the log file is created but it is empty. If I use `snort -q -l /var/log/snort` command, the log file created and filled with logs. What should I do in order to use `service snortd start` and have the logs work?

Comment: Although you are using snort, this is not a security question but a Linux system admin question.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the init file in `/etc/init.d/snortd` and add `-q -l /var/log/snort` to the command.